# tcl: eval and exec confusing point

Tags: tcl, exec, eval

I am a little confused by the `exec` and `eval` in Tcl. In the following example:

```
set cmd "mkdir new_folder";
exec $cmd
```

doesn't work with error message : `couldn't execute "mkdir new_folder" no such file or directory.`
and with `eval` it works

```
set cmd "mkdir new_folder";
eval exec $cmd
```

I also tried this way:

```
set cmd_1 "mkdir";
set cmd_2 "new_folder"
exec $cmd_1 $cmd_2
```

It also works well. 
so what's the reason?

Comment: Ok, I guess I know the reason. The first program failed, because it regards `mkdir new_folder` as a program to call, as it  is put inside a single string; and the second program works, since `eval` concat the following part into a command list; and the third one works, since I pass two separated strings to `exec`.

Comment: If you're just making directories, check out `file mkdir`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you really have to watch out is when one of your parameters contains whitespace. In that case, `eval` won't know what to do:

```
% set cmd "mkdir 'dir with spaces'"
mkdir 'dir with spaces'
% eval exec $cmd
% exec ls -l
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:51 'dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:51 spaces'
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:51 with
```

What you really want to do is to use a list. Then Tcl understands exactly what the separate elements are

```
% set cmd [list mkdir "dir with spaces"]
mkdir {dir with spaces}
% exec {*}$cmd
% exec ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:51 'dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:53 dir with spaces
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:51 spaces'
drwxr-xr-x 2 glennj glennj 4096 Feb 12 07:51 with
```

Comment: Another way to create the list is as follows: `set cmd {mkdir {dir with spaces}}`.  And if you are using an old version of tcl, you will not be able to use the expansion operator `{*}` with exec.  Instead just use `eval exec $cmd`.

Comment: P.S.  `eval $cmd` also works since `eval` does expansion automatically.

Answer (score 3):

As it is already implied in your own comment, the issue is with the interpretation of parameters. If you still want to have the command in single string you could use expansion operator `{*}`.

```
set cmd "mkdir new_folder"
exec {*}$cmd ;# Tcl 8.5 or higher
eval exec $cmd ;# alternative solution
```

This does not only pertain to  `exec` command. The general rule is: if a command accepts multiple paramaters, and say are stored in a variable `params`, when you call the command the paramaters have to be expanded:
`cmd {*}$params`.
Thus, these following scripts are equivlent

```
cmd param1 param2
```

and

```
set params "param1 param2"
cmd {*}$params
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. {*} also works for me. That is alternative method, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see this post is old, I just put my answer in as my friend asked about this.
So imaging the case you just execute the command in bash shell and want to create a directory. In this case you would run:

- `mkdir new_folder`

But now imaging what will happen if you run the same command as follows:

- `"mkdir new_folder"`

Of course if will throw an error saying:

> bash: mkdir new_folder: command not found

Now it is the same with TCL exec command, when you pass everything as single argument to exec it goes same way to the bash:

- exec "mkdir new_filder" # will actually execute:
- "mkdir new_folder"  # in the bash and hense will throw an error

Now why eval helps? just because it removes scopes after evaluation in TCL, and you actually execute:  exec mkdir new_folder

Hope this helps!